# Why not reuse schoolbooks from older siblings?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, the Weasleys buy at least one second-hand schoolbook for Ginny:

> "Busy time at the ministry, I hear," said Mr. Malfoy. "All those raids... I hope they're paying you overtime?"
>   He reached into Ginny's cauldron and extracted, from amid the glossy Lockhart books, a very old, very battered copy of *A Beginner's Guide to Transfiguration.*

Why buy books that Fred, George, and probably also Percy needed before? Why not just take those and reuse them, like happens in real life if siblings with a short age difference go to the same school?

Comment: Because the Weasley family are as poor as church mice. Presumably they're selling the books when they don't need them that year, then buying them back second-hand when they need them.

Comment: Because each book has a "magic code" that can be used during end-of-term exams for extra points, but the code [can only be used once](http://blog.cappex.com/blog/news-oped/the-problem-with-textbook-access-codes/).

Comment: @davidbak ... how does that explain the purchase of secondhand books? Surely the "code" in those books would have been used already, too...

Comment: @Catija - Keygenus Maximos!

Comment: @Catija - Oh yeah, well, ok: because the textbooks [are revised each year](http://www.psychologicalscience.org/index.php/publications/observer/2005/january-05/why-are-textbooks-so-expensive.html) and the publisher's are in cahoots with the Ministry so that the end-of-year exams reflect material in _that year's_ edition.

Comment: @davidbak - Except that they're buying old textbooks.

Comment: So @davidbak are you just using this question's comment thread to complain about textbook publishers? If so, that doesn't really seem to relate to the question at all.

Comment: @Catija - was I complaining?  I was explaining what was going on with used textbooks.  We _know_ how the Ministry behaves; you don't think it plausible that this kind of thing is going on?  If I had canon proof I'd have made an answer, but without that, only a comment thread....  Plus we _know_ that in some ways magic professors behave like Muggle professors - case in point: Lockhart assigning his own books! - so why not believe that the magical textbook industry has similarities too?

Comment: Because your arguments don't make sense... real textbooks don't get you bonus points on your tests... they just get you access to websites with other teaching materials... and you don't have to buy new books to get the code, you can buy the old text and then buy the code separately if you want... and, as has been pointed out twice, the fact that they're still buying used books negates both of your comments... so there's no logical connection between your posting of articles about textbooks and this question's discussion of used books.

Comment: I think he was just making a joke about how textbook publishers republish the same book every year so students have to keep buying new versions, and everyone else took it to far :P

Comment: @Valorum: "Because the Weasley family are as poor as church mice." - then why buy any books at all? Or do magical schools in the HP world somehow not have enough books for all pupils to borrow?

Comment: @o.r.mapper - As we've seen from Half-blood Prince, it's useful to be able to annotate the book, something you're discouraged from doing in a library book.

Comment: @Valorum: If you're really that poor, there are probably more economic ways of making annotations while still borrowing the book, but maybe they did not think of that.

Comment: @Valorum: while your suggestion about buying and selling the books sounded first odd, and from an long term economic point of view even counterproductive, I ended seeing in your suggestion an example scenario where being extremely poor ends being expensive.

Comment: @DarkPurpleShadow - Imagine allocating £5 for books costing £1 each. In the first year, you spend all £5 on 5 books. The following year you only need four of those books and a fifth that you don't own. You sell the extra book for 50p and buy the new book for £1. At some point in the future you need the old book back so you buy it again for £1. You've made a loss of 50p, but annualised it over 3 years instead of having to spend £2 annualised over 2 years.

Answer (score 8):

### The curriculum probably had changed

Professors have the freedom to set their own coursework and textbooks. There is undoubtedly some consistency across professors, of course. For example, *The Standard Book of Spells* (being standard) is used by a variety of teachers, including Filius Flitwick and Severus Snape.

On  the other hand, many classes will use non-standard books, at the professor's discretion. The most extreme case, of course, is Defense Against the Dark Arts, where the books ranged  from Gilderoy Lockhart's works to *Defensive Magical Theory*.

**Given that professors have such extreme latitude in setting book requirements, it seems most likely that the required book simply had changed between years.** 
While the same professor (McGonagall) was teaching Transfiguration, she could easily have changed the textbooks she used.  Maybe the Ministry had set new requirements, or maybe she had simply found another that she preferred.

Comment: Another possibility is that the Weasleys only ever had *one* copy, which their children shared, and which was somehow lost or damaged.

Comment: While I can see why they have to buy new books when some professor assigns new ones (like Lockhart did), in that example they seem to buy an ancient copy. It sounds to me that this ancient _A Beginner's Guide to Transfiguration_ book is ancient because it is assigned since a long time.
It could of course also be that it was once assigned long ago, then someone decided to use something else, and then it was reassigned again.
Or as Adamant suggests, it Fred/Goerge/Ron's copy was too damaged or lost.

Comment: @DarkPurpleShadow - I'm sure it had been assigned at one point. I'm just not sure it was assigned when the other Weasley children were at school.

Comment: Well, yes, that is also possible. 
Also my previous comment has been published before I was done with writing... U_U